# Relation between two solutions $f(x,y)=0$ and $f(x+\alpha, y+\beta)=0$ of two differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving this question.
Let $f(x,y)=0$ be a solution of homogenous D. E. $(2x+5y)dx+(-x-3y)dy=0$. If $f(x+\alpha, y-3)=0$ is a solution of D. E. $(2x+5y-1)dx+(2-x-3y)dy=0$. Then the value of $\alpha$ is-
I started as follows.
Let $X=x+\alpha$ and $Y=y-3$, which gives $dX=dx$ and $dY=dy$.
Using the above substitution, we have $f(X,Y)=0$ is a solution of $(2X+5Y+(-2\alpha+14))dX+(-X-3Y+\alpha-7)dY=0$.
Now if we set $\alpha=7$, we will have similar situation to first condition but in variables $X$ and $Y$.
The answer given is also $\alpha=7$ but I am unable to actually make sense of what does this means. 
I mean why $\alpha$ must be $7$ and can't be any other value?